# Execute select against each row returned by a subquery/table and combine(union) result

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I want to execute a select statement against each row of a set returned by a subquery/table. I then want to combine the results and view it as a single set.

I have a table tbl1 -

```
city|zip|contractor|budget
==========================
LA  |010| A        | 100
LA  |010| A        | 200
LA  |010| B        | 50
LA  |010| D        | 25
LA  |020| A        | 400
LA  |020| C        | 200
LA  |020| C        | 350
```

The first statement that I am executing is  -

```
select group,city,sum(budget) from tbl1 group by city,zip
```

This results in a table like this (tbl2) -

```
city|zip||budget
==========================
LA  |010|375
LA  |020|950
```

On this table I then want to run a query to rank the TOP 2 contractors. So I want the following statement to run for every row in tbl2 and then combine(union) the results -

```
    select TOP 2 contractor,sum(budget) as budget_sum from tbl1 where city = <city_value_for_row> and zip = <zip_value_for_row> 
group by contractor order by budget_sum desc
```

My final desired table is this:

```
    city|zip|contractor|budget_sum
    ==========================
    LA  |010| A        | 300
    LA  |010| B        | 50  
    LA  |020| C        | 550
    LA  |020| A        | 400
```

^^The first two lines I will get from executing the select against row 1 on tbl2.
The second two lines are a result of the executing select against row 2 from tbl2.

In other words I want to be able to rank contractors based on a group of city and zip and I want to do this for every possible combination of city and zip.

Is there a set based way to do this? Or would I have to iterate over each row in tbl2, execute select, insert into a temp table and then get the results?

Comment: Your question is rather unclear.  Where does 250 come from?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want aggregation with two keys:

```
select city, zip, contractor, sum(budget) as budget_sum
from tbl1 
group by city, zip, contractor
order by budget_sum desc;
```

EDIT:

For your revised question, use window functions:

```
select *
from (select city, zip, contractor,
             sum(budget) as budget_sum,
             row_number() over (partition by city, zip order by sum(budget) desc) as seqnum
      from tbl1 
      group by city, zip, contractor
     ) x
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Comment: that would result in an order like this: LA|020|C|550, LA|020|A|50. The reason for this question is that I want to get the TOP 2 contractors for each combination of zip and city. Edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the 2 queries:

```
select t.city, t.zip, t.contractor, t.tsum
from (
  select 
    t.city, t.zip, t.contractor, g.budget_sum gsum, t.budget_sum tsum,
    row_number() over (partition by t.city, t.zip order by g.budget_sum, t.budget_sum desc) rn  
  from (
    select city, zip, contractor, sum(budget) budget_sum
    from tbl1 
    group by city, zip, contractor
  )  t inner join (
    select city, zip, sum(budget) budget_sum
    from tbl1 
    group by city, zip  
  ) g 
  on g.city = t.city and g.zip = t.zip
) t
where t.rn <= 2
order by t.gsum, t.tsum desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/eGxGAR317sBJDXbDyDeaLq/2).
Results:

```
| city | zip | contractor | budget_sum |
| ---- | --- | ---------- | ---------- |
| LA   | 10  | A          | 300        |
| LA   | 10  | B          | 50         |
| LA   | 20  | C          | 550        |
| LA   | 20  | A          | 400        |
```

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question a little where I indicated that I wanted TOP 2 only. Also added another contractor 'D'. Will this work on that as well?

Comment: If you want the top 2 only why in your results there are 3: A, B, C?

Comment: that's for a different grouping |LA|20|C|